# Ito's lemma and Milstein approximation for this two SDE, am I correct?

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, variance, stochastic-differential-equations

**First check**
I considered the Constant Elasticity of Variance (CEV) model:
$$
dS = S\mu dt + S^\alpha \sigma dW
$$
and numerically approximated it with the Milstein method:
$$
S(t+dt) = S(t) + S(t)\cdot \mu \cdot dt + S(t)^\alpha \cdot \sigma \cdot \varepsilon_t \cdot \sqrt{dt} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \alpha \cdot S(t)^{2\alpha-1} \cdot \sigma^2 \cdot \left( (\varepsilon_t \cdot \sqrt{dt})^2 -dt \right)
$$
where $\varepsilon_t$ is a random variable with mean 0 and variance 1. Then I applied ito's lemma to the process $X= \ln S$:
$$
d \ln S = \left(\mu - \frac{S^{2\alpha - 2} \sigma^2}{2} \right)dt + S^{\alpha-1}\sigma dW
$$

**Second check**
I considered the following modification of the  Constant Elasticity of Variance (CEV) model:
$$
dS = S\mu dt + S^\alpha \sigma_1 dW_1 + S\sigma_2dW_2
$$
which I call Modified CEV, and numerically approximated it with the Milstein method:
$$
S(t+dt) = S(t) + S(t)\cdot \mu \cdot dt + S(t)^\alpha \cdot \sigma_1 \cdot \varepsilon_t \cdot \sqrt{dt} + S(t) \cdot \sigma_2 \cdot \epsilon_t \cdot \sqrt{dt} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \alpha \cdot S(t)^{2\alpha-1} \cdot \sigma_1^2 \cdot \left( (\varepsilon_t \cdot \sqrt{dt})^2 -dt \right) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot S(t) \cdot \sigma_2^2 \cdot \left( (\epsilon_t \cdot \sqrt{dt})^2 -dt \right)
$$
where $\varepsilon_t$ and $\epsilon_t$ are two random variables with mean 0 and variance 1. Then I applied ito's lemma to the process $X= \ln S$:
$$
d \ln S = \left(\mu - \frac{S^{2\alpha-2}\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2+2S^{\alpha+1}\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho_{12}}{2} \right)dt + S^{\alpha-1} \sigma_1 dW_1 + \sigma_2 dW_2
$$
where I used the fact that $dW_1 \cdot dW_2 = \rho_{12}dt$.\

By implementing numerical simulation starting from the same diffusions ($\varepsilon_t$ and $\epsilon_t$) for $T=2$ years and $dt=1/12$ months, $\sigma_1 = 0.12$ and $\sigma_2 = 0.105$, $\mu=0$ I compared 4 different models:

1. Modified CEV with $\alpha = 1$ approximated with Euler method;
2. Modified CEV with $\alpha = 1$ approximated with Milstein method;
3. Modified CEV with $\alpha \neq 1$ approximated with Euler method;
4. Modified CEV with $\alpha \neq 1$ approximated with Milstein method;

The result is that differences in the process 1., 2., 4. dynamics are negligible, BUT the process 3. dynamic is significantly different from the others. I can't understand why this happens.

In the plot $\alpha = 0.5$:

[image: Numerical Approximation]

Comment: What lets you suspect that something is wrong? What precisely is your question? /// In the case of $α\ne 1$ I would also try $S^\beta$ instead of the logarithm $\ln S$, probably with $\beta=1-α$. /// The Milstein method only works in its simple form for scalar Brownian motions. If you have two independent BM in the equation, you get cross-over terms related to $\int W_1dW_2$ etc. that can not be solved to integral-free expressions. In Milsteins original paper this case was only mentioned in a short notice at the end, so this distinction is frequently overlooked.

Comment: I just wanted to check the math. I suspect there is something wrong because I simulated 4 different processes from the same $\varepsilon_t$ and $\epsilon_t$ random variables as follows: 1. simulation with euler method for $\alpha=1$, 2. simulation with milstein method for $\alpha=1$, 3. simulation with euler method for $\alpha \neq 0$, 4. simulation with milstein method with $\alpha \neq 0$. The result is that differences in process 1., 2., 4. are negligible, BUT the process 3. is significantly different from the others. I can't understand why this happens, so my doubt.

Comment: You should add that to the question text, with a little more detail on what equation you refer to. What does $α\ne0$ mean practically? What exactly is the type of results you compare, and how is 3. different? How can 4. be similar to 1. and 2.?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question to be more clear

Comment: @LutzLehmann what's the purpose when considering the dynamics of $S^\beta$?

Comment: Because the form of the DE then resembles a Bernoulli equation. It might not work out with the Ito formula, just was a relevant idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the proof of the orders of Milstein's method is more complicated, its construction can be easily obtained by one iteration of the integral equation. In the SDE (for scalar $X$)
$$
dX_t=a(X_t)\,dt+\vec b(X_t)^Td\vec W_t
$$
and for its first step with $X_0=x$ take the Euler-Maruyama formula as first approximation
$$
\hat X_t=x+a(x)t+\vec b(x)^T\vec W_t
$$
Then insert into the integral equation and use Taylor expansions of the coefficient formulas to get the next-higher error order $t^1$ or $\|\vec W_t\|^2$,
\begin{align}
X_t&=x+\int_0^t a(\hat X_s)\,ds+\int_0^t \vec b(\hat X_s)^T\,d\vec W_s\\
&=x+a(x)t+\int_0^t [\vec b(x)+\vec b'(x)\vec b(x)^T\vec W_s]^T\,d\vec W_s+O(t^{3/2})\\
&=x+a(x)t+\vec b(x)^T\vec W_t+{\rm trace}\left(\vec b'(x)\vec b(x)^T·\int_0^t\vec W_s\,d\vec W_s^T\right)+O(t^{3/2})
\end{align}
Of the matrix of integrals in the last term, only the diagonal entries can be solved to the form you already used. The non-diagonal entries have to be sufficiently approximated by other means.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, so my Milstein scheme implementation looks fine. I derived it from the multidimensional ito's lemma which looks very similar to your last equation.

Comment: Using the formulation of the weak convergence and applying Ito is also about how Milstein introduced his method. But your formula is missing the off-diagonal terms, these are non-trivial here. This reduces its orders to the ones of the Euler method.

Comment: So if I want to simulate the modified CEV, the approximation with the Euler method (grey line in the plot that corresponds to point 3.) is the more suitable? And this happens because it takes into account, even if not accurately, the off diagonal elements of the matrix?

Comment: What if I use Cholesky decomposition to evaluate the matrix?

Comment: There should be no big difference between Euler and your Milstein, as the latter is only a small perturbation of the former, done correctly or not. There could be an error, a typo, in your implementation. You will need Cholesky to transform the correlated BM from uncorrelated BM, but that will not get rid of the non-local integral terms.

Comment: Thank you, I will check!